# UIDocumentInteractionController works but doesn't show "Save Image"

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I create and present a `UIDocumentInteractionController` with a valid url to a saved image but when I present the controller "Save Image" does not appear.

```
NSURL *url = ...;
self.interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[self.interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
```

I have verified `self.interactionController.UTI` is a valid image type (jpeg)

### ______Actual_______ vs.____Expected_____

[image: Actual image]____ [image: Expected image]

Note* If anyone knows a better way to format those images please be my guest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the option to save to the camera roll, the app must have permission to access photos.

Relative to `ALAuthorizationStatus` ([`[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ALAuthorizationStatus))

"Save Image" is displayed for

1. `ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`
2. `ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`

"Save Image" is not displayed for

1. `ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted`
2. `ALAuthorizationStatusDenied`

You can do a check like this:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

- (BOOL)canSaveToCameraRoll
{
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    return (status == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized || status == ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined);
}
```

Comment: Should be "...(status == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized || ...), but I cant edit your post  because its only a 1 character change.